# Spring returns 401 instead of 200 status

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I wrote an application as part of learning Spring, but when I test authentication I receive 401 status instead of 200. I was looking for the cause of the error and it seems to me that the line `Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, password));` returns `null`. However, I do not know how to solve this problem.

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationServiceUsernamePassword {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationServiceUsernamePassword.class);
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customAuthenticationManager")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private TokenManager tokenManager;

    public SignedJWT authenticate(final String email, final String password){
        try {
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
                .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, password));        
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .setAuthentication(authentication);

            if (authentication.getPrincipal() != null) {
                return tokenManager.createNewToken((PrincipalUser) authentication.getPrincipal());
            }
        } catch (AuthenticationException authException) {
            LOGGER.debug("Authentication failed for user:\"" + email + ".\" Reason " + authException.getClass());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

*Controller*

```
@Controller
public class AuthController {
    @Value("${jwt.result}")
    private String defaultTokenResponse;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationServiceUsernamePassword authUserPassword;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authentication", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> authenticate(String email, String password, HttpServletRequest request,
                                           HttpServletResponse response){
        if (email != null && password != null){
            try {
                SignedJWT token = authUserPassword.authenticate(email, password);

                if (token != null){
                    return new ResponseEntity<String>(String.format(defaultTokenResponse, token.serialize()),
                        HttpStatus.OK);
                } else {
                    return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
                }
            } catch (BadCredentialsException badCredentials) {
                return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }
}
```

*Test class:*

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ConnectControllerTest {
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;
    @Autowired
    private Filter springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
            .addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain)
            .defaultRequest(get("/"))
            .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldTestAuthentication() throws Exception {
        String result = mockMvc.perform(post("/authentication")
            .param("email", "user@test.pl").param("password", "password"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.token").exists())
            .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
    }
}
```

If anyone would be interested in the rest of the code here is the link: [repository](https://github.com/mmaciula/spring-jwt)

Comment: Do you get a nullpointerexception? Or is the log message in your catch clause written to your log?

Comment: @SvenHakvoort None of the above. I just get `java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<401>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct, it goes wrong in your controller definition:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> authenticate(String email, String password, HttpServletRequest request,
                                           HttpServletResponse response){
```

Spring does not know how to retrieve the email and password variables by default. You need to annotate these with the `@RequestBody` annotation, like:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> authenticate(@RequestBody String email, @RequestBody String password, HttpServletRequest request,
                                           HttpServletResponse response){
```

However if your whole controller will serve as an API you can also annotate your controller with `@RestController` which tells spring to use the `@RequestBody` for every parameter and that every method should be annotated with `@ResponseBody` which will tell spring that the return values should be converted to JSON (which is convenient for an API).

References:

[Spring’s RequestBody and ResponseBody Annotations](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body)

Comment: I annotated my controller with `@RestController`, but it didn't fix the problem. Using the `@RequestBody` annotation in turn change the status to `400`.

Comment: Use @ RequestParam and not @ RequestBody.

Comment: @VishwPatel, this is incorrect. `@RequestParam` is for GET variables and not for POST params.

Answer (score 3):

Ok. First thing first

`Email` and `Password` are passed correctly

Problem is here

```
public SignedJWT authenticate(final String email, final String password){
        try {
            System.out.println("test => "+email+" : "+password);
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
                    .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, password));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

            if (authentication.getPrincipal() != null) {
                return tokenManager.createNewToken((PrincipalUser) authentication.getPrincipal());
            }
        } catch (AuthenticationException authException) {
            authException.printStackTrace();
            LOGGER.debug("Authentication failed for user:\"" + email + ".\" Reason " + authException.getClass());
        }
        System.out.println("return nulll");
        return null;
    }
```

If you run your test case it will throw following error

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:98)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:504)
    at com.github.springjwt.security.jwt.service.AuthenticationServiceUsernamePassword.authenticate(AuthenticationServiceUsernamePassword.java:30)
    at com.github.springjwt.web.api.controller.AuthController.authenticate(AuthController.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImp
```

Which means your testcase's `username` and `password` didnt match with `UserRepository` class User detail

In your `UserRepository` class
 you need to set a correct hashed password and its salt value which you have set to null.

When you call `authenticate.authenticate`  it internally gets password and hash and matched it with passed value.

If values doesn't match it throws Bad credentials error

**P.S :** I came to this conclusion after running your code locally

Comment: What if I changed current `UserRepository` to `public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User UUID>`? Do I still have to set up hashed password in this situation?

Comment: yes you can. Bottomline is password passed and hashed password should match  after encoding using salt logic. ELse you will get 404.

Comment: I changed my `UserRepository` and created my test User with matching data but still get 401. I probably do something wrong, but I Can't figure out what.  All the changes I made are visible in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

You have added params to you unit test case. Not payload. If you add payload then you have to use @RequestBody. Here you have to use @RequestParam.  Use below code in controller :

```
public ResponseEntity<String> authenticate(@RequestParam String email, @RequestParam String password, HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
 ..do stuff
}
```

This will work ..!